# How does the recursing work in prolog for adding number

Tags: prolog

My aim is to take the numbers between X and Y and produce Z.

```
num_between(3,6, All)
```

For example, if X is 3 and Y is 6 then Z is a list of the numbers between X and Y inclusive. Something like `num_between(3,6,[3,4,5,6])` should evaluate as `true`. Here's what I have so far:

```
num_between(0,0, []).
num_between(X,Y, All) :- 
  increase(X, New) ,           % increase number X++
  \+(X = Y) ,                  % check if  X is not equal to Y
  num_between(New,Y,[All|X]) . % requestion ???

increase(F,N) :- N is F+1 .
```

`increase/1` is working and returns number that is required, but
when recursion is gone through `num_between/3` it goes unlit: X is 6 then it fails as I want,
but I can not manage to keep numbers or to return them. All = [3,4,5,6].

All =  All + F. Could anyone help please.

Comment: what if `Y > X`? Is there never a case for `[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base clause is incorrect: since you never decrease `X` or `Y`, they would never get to zero (unless `Y` starts at zero, and `X` starts at a non-positive value). The base clause should look like this:

```
num_between(X, Y, []) :- X > Y.
```

This ensures that you get an empty result when the user enters an invalid "backward" range (say, from 6 to 3).

Now to the main clause: all you need to do is to check that the range is valid, get the next value, and make a recursive call, like this:

```
num_between(X, Y, [X|Tail]) :-
    X =< Y,
    Next is X + 1,
    num_between(Next, Y, Tail).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/jXULoE)

Your original code made an error when constructing a list - it tried to use `X` as the "tail" of the list, which is incorrect:

```
num_between(New,Y,[All|X]).
```

you pass on `All`, the result after an "expansion", down through the recursive chain of invocation. It should be the other way around - you need to pass in a `Tail` to collect the result, and then pre-pend `X` to it when the recursive invocation is over.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change both your base case and your recursive clause:

```
num_between(X, X, [X]).
num_between(X, Y, [X|L]):-
  X < Y,
  increase(X, New),
  num_between(New, Y, L).
```

First clause is the base case, it states that the number ranging from X and X is just `[X]`.

The recursive clause states that a number `X` which is less than a number `Y` should have it in the output list (thus the `[X|L]` in the third argument of the head), then it increases the value (i'm just using your helper procedure for that) and recursively calling itself now with the `New` value for the first argument.

Comment: Thank you. It is nice explain and it works exactly as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this along these lines:

```
numbers_between( X , X , [X]    ) .   % if X and Y have converged, we have the empty list
numbers_between( X , Y , [X|Zs] ) :-  % otherwise, add X to the result list
  X < Y ,                             % - assuming X is less than Y
  X1 is X+1 ,                         % - increment X
  numbers_between(X1,Y,Zs)            % - recurse down
  .                                   %
numbers_between( X , Y , [X|Zs] ) :-  % otherwise, add X to the result list
  X > Y ,                             % - assuming X > Y
  X1 is X-1 ,                         % - decrement X
  numbers_between(X1,Y,Zs)            % - recurse down
  .                                   %
```